# how to use async-await in protractor?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, protractor

**I have updated my node.js version above the 7.6 and i am using ES6.I have also attached the error message.I am using jasmine and javascript for writing test.Without aysnc-await its working fine..I am not able to figure out why below error is coming .Any help will be highly apppreciated**

```
  My code is :-
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  describe("testing login functionalties", function() {

     it("entering the text", async function () {

    browser.get("https://weather.com/en-IN");
    //console.log('ddd')
    browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
    element(by.xpath("//button[@class='user-login']")).click()
    //browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
    console.log('ddd')
    element(by.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("offsite.mail1@gmail.com");
    element(by.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
    var a= element(by.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-disabled sign-button login-button']"));
    await a.getText();
    console.log(a);
    a.click();


});
```

});

```
    And the error i am getting is:-
    /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.9.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js /Users/amrit/WebstormProjects/E2E/conf.js
    (node:13230) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
    (node:13230) DeprecationWarning: `DEBUG_FD` is deprecated. Override `debug.log` if you want to use a different log function (https://git.io/vMUyr)
    [16:03:41] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
    [16:03:41] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
    [16:03:42] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.101.23.28:60360/wd/hub
    Started
    F

    Failures:
    1) testing login functionalties encountered a declaration exception
      Message:
        Error: async function () {

                browser.get("https://weather.com/en-IN");
                //console.log('ddd')
                browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
                element(by.xpath("//button[@class='user-login']")).click()
                //browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
                console.log('ddd')
                element(by.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("offsite.mail1@gmail.com");
                element(by.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
                var a= element(by.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-disabled sign-button login-button']"));
                await a.getText();
                console.log(a);
                a.click();


            } is not a function
      Stack:
        Error: async function () {

                browser.get("https://weather.com/en-IN");
                //console.log('ddd')
                browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
                element(by.xpath("//button[@class='user-login']")).click()
                //browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
                console.log('ddd')
                element(by.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("offsite.mail1@gmail.com");
                element(by.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
                var a= element(by.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-disabled sign-button login-button']"));
                await a.getText();
                console.log(a);
                a.click();


            } is not a function
            at validateFunction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:30:11)
            at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:116:16
            at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/amrit/WebstormProjects/E2E/Describe.js:8:5)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/amrit/WebstormProjects/E2E/Describe.js:6:1)
            at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:488:32)

    1 spec, 1 failure
    Finished in 0.011 seconds
    [16:03:44] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
    [16:03:44] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
    [16:03:44] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
    [16:03:44] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
    [16:03:44] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: remove the word 'async' inside `it`.

Comment: then how to use async-await ??

Comment: For non-angular pages `browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;` will do the trick. If you need to wait for an element. You need to use `browser.sleep(1000)`

Comment: async-await isn't related to `browser.ingoreSynchronization = true`. @AmritPalSingh, I know [this doc](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript/asyncAwait) is for TypeScript, but did you set all the configs correct conform this doc like, setting the config, compiling the code and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran a quick test and was able to reproduce your error. With a little debugging, it seems the issue is Jasmine (at least the one that ships with Protractor 5.1.1). I was able to get `async-await` working by installing [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), and selecting it as the `framework` in the config.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4186, as far as I know it's fixed in release 5.1.2. So you should update your protractor and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned on my comment remove the word `async`.
Setting `browser.ignoreSynchronization` as true will do the trick for non-angular page.

Also update your code, it might fail on getText.
Also, I am not a fan of xpath, I suggest using by.css instead.

```
describe('testing login functionalties', function() {
    it("entering the text", function () {   
        browser.get("https://weather.com/en-IN");

        browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
            element(by.css('[@class="user-login"]')).click()

            console.log('ddd')
            element(by.css('[type="email"]')).sendKeys('offsite.mail1@gmail.com');
            element(by.css('[type="password"]')).sendKeys('xxxxx');
            var a = element(by.css('.btn.btn-disabled.sign-button.login-button'));
            a.getText().then(function(tmpText) {
            console.log(tmpText);
        });
            a.click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Downvoted the answer. He is not asking for a non Angular page. The question is about how to use [async-await](http://rossboucher.com/await/#/) in combination with Protractor

Comment: I am giving a different solution, i think it is not appropriate to downvote all answer that does not fit your liking. It is their choice if they will use it or not.

Comment: You should read the question, the question is `..Without aysnc-await its working fine..`, so your answer isn't related to the question

Comment: Are you stating that you will not provide a different solution if you can't answer the question? sounds helpful :)